# Extracting specific information out of string

Tags: php

I have a string that contains an address to a youtube video, I want to use this to display the video in a pop-up lightbox.  In the current form the link will not work in the lightbox:

```
http://www.youtube.com/v/CD2LRROpph0?f=videos&c=TEST&app=youtube_gdata&version=3
```

I has an idea to extract the video id 'CD2LRROpph0' and just append that to a regular youtube url, for example

```
http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=CD2LRROpph0.
```

Which i know works in the lightbox.

Any ideas on how to extract this code from the string???

Answer (score 1):

This one will handle different protocols and different YouTube URLs (in case YouTube come out with country specific TLDs, for example).

```
$urlTokens = parse_url($url);

$newUrl = $urlTokens['scheme'] . '://' . $urlTokens['host'] . '/watch?v=' . preg_replace('~^/v/~', '', $urlTokens['path']);
```

[CodePad](http://codepad.org/UomraSH4).

Answer (score 0):

```
$newUrl = preg_replace('@http://www.youtube.com/v/([a-z0-9_\-]{11}).*$@i', 
   'http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=$1', $string);
```

Answer (score 0):

Or try this, you get an array back and can use the query you want
http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.parse-url.php

Comment: may be you don't have to use serverside parsing either and use javascript instead.